# How to get all field's title of object

Tags: java, string, object, reflection, field

I need to write a method. The meaning is to send any object(Entity etc) as parameter and get all fields names as return values. Something like that.

**Example of method**

```java
public String getFieldsTitle(Object obj){

   return obj.getListOfFields();

}
```

**Entity for example:**

```java
public class Human{
private String name;

private String fam;

private String patr;

}
```

**Expectation value of method**

> [name,fam,patr]

Comment: I assume it is java but it is not obvious. Please replace "string" tag with relevant language

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list of `List<String>` from your `getFieldsTitle` method and then print the list.

**Using Java 8**

```
public static List<String> getFieldsTitle(Object obj){
    return Arrays.stream(obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .map(Field::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

There are two methods for this

```
// returns inherited members but not private members.
Field[] fields = ClassName.class.getFields(); 

// returns all members including private members but not inherited members.
Field[] fields = ClassName.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

See [oracle docs of classMembers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) for more details.